# XNA Load Data from StorageDevice

Tags: c#, xna, storage

My XNA game needs to load data from `StorageContainer` ("StorageDemo") at

> Documents\SavedGames\WindowsGame1\StorageDemo

some classifiers and videos.

Every time I install the game in another machine it creates another `StorageDemo` folder at same location, empty of course, and could not find those files into it.

I previously have installed the `StorageDemo` folder through Advance Installer.

There is a way to save those files through Visual Studio? or I can access them through code without duplicating the folder?

This is the piece of code related.

```
//loads the signpacks from My Documents
private void DoLoadSignPacks(StorageDevice device, Game1 game1)
{
    ContentManager content = game1.Content;

    // Open a storage container.
    IAsyncResult result =
       device.BeginOpenContainer("StorageDemo", null, null);

    // Wait for the WaitHandle to become signaled.
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(result);

    // Close the wait handle.
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();

    //Load  the data from this floder storage folder///
    string root = Path.GetDirectoryName("SignPacks\\");
}
```

Thanks in advance.